# Image classification: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

i am practicing image classifcaiton project. i am getting

here is the code i used. can any give suggest where i am doing wrong.

```
# Predict
test_batch_x, test_batch_y = test_gen.next()
pred_batch = model.predict(test_batch_x)

test_labels = np.argmax(test_batch_y, axis=1)
test_pred = np.argmax(pred_batch, axis=1)
```

It throwing this error at `test_batch_x, test_batch_y = test_gen.next()`

```
 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

can someone give suggestion on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, that the method `next()` does not return two values,
but you try to unpack the result into two variables.

Since you created `test_gen` using `flow_from_directory`, it is a tf.data.Dataset: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset.

I think next only returns one value, because no label was defined `class_mode=None`.

Comment: test_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=TEST_DIR, 
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), 
    batch_size=TEST_BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False    )

Comment: Thanks. I think you should include this in the question. `class_mode=None` does disable labels, so this could be a reason why `next()` only returns one value one not an image - label pair.